# how to access used_id fromthe database?

Tags: php, mysql

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in D:\xampp\htdocs\E-commerce website\users_area\payment.php on line 34

am trying to access users_id from the database but am getting this error message

```
<?php
    $user_ip=getIPAddress();
    $get_user="select * from `user_table` where user_ip='$user_ip'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$get_user);
    $run_query=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $user_id=$run_query['user_id'];
    ?>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center text-info">payment options</h2>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center my-5">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <a href="https://www.paypal.com" target="_blank"><img src="../assets/photos/paypal.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <a href="order.php?user_id=<?php echo $user_id ?>"><h2 class="text-center">pay offline</h2></a>
    <!-- <a href="order.php"><h2 class="text-center">pay offline</h2></a> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
$sql = "select * from `user_table` where user_ip='$user_ip'";
$result = $mysqli -> query($sql);

// Numeric array
$row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

// Associative array
$row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["user_id"]);
```